# Setting Default Page in EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on hosting a website developed using asp.net to AWS. I have successfully published it to EC2 instance. I want to setup Index.aspx page as default page so that if someone open the URL it should automatically load index.aspx page e.g. typing www.domain.com opens up index.aspx page. I have tried all the options but somehow its not working for me. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: whats your web server (Apache ...) ?

Comment: I am using IIS on AWS

Comment: look your `web.config` make sure you have `<defaultDocument enabled="true">` and/or there's `<add value="index.aspx"/>`

Comment: Its working now. Thanks @FrédéricHenri

Comment: good making an answer to facilitate search

Answer (score 1):

For IIS Web Server you should look at the `web.config` file.

Make sure you have `<defaultDocument enabled="true">`

The default files in recent IIS version are (in order)

- index.htm
- index.html
- default.asp
- default.aspx
- index.asp
- index.aspx
- index.cfm
- index.php
- default.htm

If you don't enable the default list, you would need to make sure your index file is added to the list

```
<defaultDocument>
   <files>      
       <add value="index.aspx"/>
       <add value="..."/>
   </files>
</defaultDocument>
```